# SSL Handshake issue with asyncio motor driver Mongodb Python

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl

I am trying to connect Mongodb using AWS lambda but results SSL handshake error. I am using motor and Python 3.8 . There is successful connection to database most of time. When I look AWS cloud watchlogs , I found a error connecting to database in some logs.

This is code for connecting database.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from .mongodb import db
import certifi
from app.utility.config import MONGODB_URL
    
async def connect_to_mongo(app: FastAPI) -> None
    db.client = AsyncIOMotorClient(str(MONGODB_URL),tls = True, tlsCAFile= certifi.where(),
                                   maxPoolSize=MAX_CONNECTIONS_COUNT,
                                   minPoolSize=MIN_CONNECTIONS_COUNT, 
                                   waitQueueMultiple = MAX_DB_THREADS_WAIT_COUNT,
                                   waitQueueTimeoutMS = MAX_DB_THREAD_QUEUE_TIMEOUT_COUNT )
    


async def close_mongo_connection(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    
    db.client.close()
```

**Traceback**

```
File "/var/task/pymongo/pool.py", line 1040, in _configured_socket
sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1114: The handshake operation timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1869, in _process_periodic_tasks
self._topology.update_pool(self.__all_credentials)
File "/var/task/pymongo/topology.py", line 456, in update_pool
server.pool.remove_stale_sockets(generation, all_credentials)
File "/var/task/pymongo/pool.py", line 1252, in remove_stale_sockets
sock_info = self.connect(all_credentials)
File "/var/task/pymongo/pool.py", line 1280, in connect
sock = _configured_socket(self.address, self.opts)
File "/var/task/pymongo/pool.py", line 1053, in _configured_socket
_raise_connection_failure(address, exc, "SSL handshake failed: ")
File "/var/task/pymongo/pool.py", line 238, in _raise_connection_failure
raise NetworkTimeout(msg)
pymongo.errors.NetworkTimeout: SSL handshake failed: cluster0-***-******mongodb.net:******: _ssl.c:1114: The handshake operation timed out
```